# Type cast in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I know there is no "cast" in Haskell but I have this expression:

```
o = sum . takeWhile (< 10000) . filter odd . map (^2) $ [1..]
```

I would like to have the result as a Double.
I tried:

```
g :: (Integral c, Double b) => [c] -> b
g =sum . takeWhile (< 10000) . filter odd . map (^2)
```

and other things like that... I always get an error.
How can I do?

Comment: `Double` is a type, not a type class. The correct type signature is `g :: Integral c => [c] -> Double` or the more general `g :: (Num a, Integral c) => [c] -> a` In general, you can use `fromIntegral` to convert any integral type to any other numeric type: `g = fromIntegral . sum . takeWhile (<10000) . filter odd . map (^2)`.

Comment: @user2407038 you should make this into an answer!

Comment: @user2407038 Lots of thanks for the fast and interesting answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
g :: [Integer] -> Double
g = fromInteger . sum . takeWhile (< 10000) . filter odd . map (^2)
```

Or, you could convert the list to [Double] before the sum by

```
g = sum . map fromInteger . takeWhile (< 10000) . filter odd . map (^2)
```

There is no generic cast in Haskell, but there are functions (like fromInteger and fromRational) which can convert from a particular type to a desired type.   The type of fromIntegral is
`fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b`
It will convert an Integral value to any kind of Num value.

Comment: Thanks so much! The two solutions work very well but, maybe, the first one is better with only one map.